# Erro ao exibir dados em um JTable usando Java + NetBeans + MySql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jtable

Estou tendo problemas para criar uma tabela no NetBeans com dados do MySql.

Basicamente, está quase tudo funcionando, a conexão com o banco está ok e está retornando todos os itens que eu preciso, mas na hora de adicionar esses dados na tabela (em uma classe form) ele repete o primeiro item na mesma quantidade de intens que existem no banco:

[image: Tabela Times no banco de dados]

Bando de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método que faz a requizição no banco e traz os times:

```
public Times [] obterTimes () throws Exception{
    String sql = "SELECT nome FROM tb_times"; 
    try (Connection conn = ConexaoBD.obterConexao(); 
        PreparedStatement ps = 
        conn.prepareStatement(sql, 
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); 
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()){ 
        int totalDeUsuarios = rs.last () ? rs.getRow() : 0; 
        Times [] times = new Times[totalDeUsuarios]; 
        rs.beforeFirst(); 
        int contador = 0; 
        while (rs.next()){ 
            String nome = rs.getString("nome"); 
            times[contador++] = new Times(nome); 
        } 
        return times; 
    }
}
```

Método que adiciona os times na lista (A tabela só recebe os valores ao clicar em atualizar):

```
private void AtualizarBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Times.getModel();
    
    DAO dao = new DAO();
    
    Vector rowName = new Vector();
    
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < dao.obterTimes().length; i++) {
            rowName.add(dao.obterTimes()[i].getNome());
            model.addRow(rowName);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ListUsers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Basicamente está funcionando, mas ele só exibe o time na posição [0].

Answer (score -1):

Você está declarando um vetor (`Vector rowName = new Vector();`) que recebe todos os itens da sua consulta. A cada iteração desses itens, você adiciona ele ao vetor e depois o vetor completo ao model;

```
rowName.add(dao.obterTimes()[i].getNome());
model.addRow(rowName);
```

Sendo assim, a "primeira linha" do seu model tem um vetor com o item *zero* da consulta; a "segunda linha" tem um vetor com os itens *zero* e *um*; e assim sucessivamente. Acredito que baste você inserir diretamente no model o *nome do time*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dao.obterTimes().length; i++) {
    model.addRow(dao.obterTimes()[i].getNome());
}
```

ou se quiser manter o controle em um vetor, adicione todos os itens à variável e só então jogue tudo no model:

```
Vector rowName = new Vector();
        
for (int i = 0; i < dao.obterTimes().length; i++) {
    rowName.add(dao.obterTimes()[i].getNome());
}

model = rowName;
```

Comment: algum motivo específico pelo _vote down_??

Comment: (Não votei em down)
Eu tentei essas duas formas, tambem não funcionou:
Se eu faço model = rowName ele da erro, se uso model.addRow(rowName), ele traz apenas um item.
Se eu fizer direto (model.addRow(dao.obterTimes()[i].getNome());) não funciona tambem

Comment: atualiza com a definição do model (classe) pra gente, por favor

Comment: O model não é bem uma classe, eu o início essa linha aqui: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Times.getModel(). Esse Times é a tabela que tem na classe form